# Рожок или ложка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, терминология

Как всё-таки правильно называть этот предмет для надевания обуви? *"Рожок"* строгое слово, а *"ложка"* разговорное?

Сам привык к *"рожку",* но от других гораздо чаще слышу слово *"ложка",* поэтому и решил спросить.

Comment: Никогда не слышал про ложку. Всегда употреблял "рожок".

Comment: Никогда не слышал про рожок, только "ложка", питерский диалект?). То ли не пользуюсь, то ли я из деревни...

Answer (score 4):

[рожо́к](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA) (БТС)
**6. *мн.:*** рожки́, -о́в. Изогнутая полукруглая лопаточка, помогающая надевать обувь, не сминая задники. *Пластмассовый, металлический рожок. Обувной рожок. Надеть туфли с помощью рожка.*

Удивительно, но в статье "[ложка](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)" (в том же БТС) значения "предмет для надевания обуви" вообще нет, даже как разговорного варианта.

[Вопрос № 219620](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA&start=0)
Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, прибор, которым мы помогаем надеть обувь, называется правильно обувная ложка, ложка для обуви или рожок для обуви или как-то по-другому?

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
Предпочтительно: *рожок, обувной рожок*.

В нашей семье эта вспомогательная вещица называется ложкой. В ближайшем окружении иногда слышу слово "лопатка", но (парадоксально!) очень и очень редко — "рожок".

Самые первые [рожки для обуви](https://art-ant.ru/magazin/product/rozhok-dlya-obuvi-2) действительно имели ложкообразную форму, отсюда, возможно, и *обиходное* название.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Что посоветуете: продолжать рожком называть или перейти на ложку (вопрос и Александру, и всем тоже)? *Удивительно, но...* — вот-вот, я вчера на Грамоте и смотрел, и этого значения тоже не нашёл. ;)

Comment: И Вам, Артём, спасибо за вопрос. Я хоть вспомнила, что у моей старшей сестры дома хранится (именно хранится — не используется) бабушкин (1909, Новгород) деревянный рожок с металлическими вставками, с желтым металлическим языком (собственно, ложкой) и желтым же набалдашником в виде конской головы, сделанной из кости. Очень похож на трость, бабушка и называла его тросточкой.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Современные наипростейшие (металлические или пластмассовые) приспособления ну никак не тянут на то, чтобы называться рожками. В таком виде (без исторических прибамбасов) пусть уж будут просто ложками.

Comment: А если он длинный красный металлический больше 20 см и с дырочкой для того, чтобы вешать — всё равно наипростейший?

Comment: Вот такой? (https://www.1d.ru/catalog/tovary_dlya_doma/prikhozhaya/lozhki_i_shchetki_dlya_obuvi/167253/) Думаю, самый обыкновенный (цена, правда, необыкновенная). Для меня — все равно ложка. Пикантности-то, секретика нет.

Comment: Почти) чуть покороче и с меньшим загибом вверху

Answer (score 3):

Для меня он всегда был язычком, хотя я вариант *рожок* считаю таким же правильным. А вот про ложку разве что от мамы пару раз слышала, и то не факт. Вообще, это в любом случае метафора/перенос по функции. Вопрос: чего больше — внешнего сходства или собственно цели использования? В гостях я бы *ложка* не сказала, потому что придётся объяснять (я думаю, меня бы скорее всего не поняли). Самое нейтральное, по-моему, рожок. Но если очень интересно, то я бы диалектологию по регионам России посмотрела — может отличаться, как и возрастные/социальные группы.

Comment: Сколько раз в гостях говорил "ложка для обуви" - ни разу не встретил непонимание.

Answer (score 2):

1. Рожок для обуви — изогнутая полукруглая лопаточка, помогающая надевать обувь, не сминая ее пяточную часть.

К сожалению, рожок для обуви **в разговорной речи заменен на «ложку» для обуви, что является ложным названием предмета,** так как у ложки совершенно иные предназначения. https://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=d47f742d-41f9-49ca-ac47-ce2156c1a7aa

А точно ли это **ложное и разговорное название?** Это еще вопрос, обоснование не очень убедительное. Рожок тоже многозначное слово. Возможно, **корректны оба названия.**

2. Первоначально, рожки были сделаны **из рога** животных, или копыта, а некоторые из копыт быков все еще доступны для покупки. Сегодня чаще всего используется пластик, металл и дерево. Они также бывают сделаны из стекла и даже бумаги. Дорогие рожки делают  из слоновой кости, серебра, скорлупы или кости.

Похоже, что рожки ( или ложки для обуви) появились **в позднем средневековье или эпохе Возрождения.**  На английском языке **«schoying horne» упоминается в 15 веке,** хотя французское слово chausse-pied встречается только во второй половине 16-го века. Элизабета I, королева  Англии,  купила 18 обувных рожков у своего сапожника Гарретта Джонсона в период между 1563 и 1566 годами.   В Британском музее есть коллекция из более чем 20 известных английских рожков для ботинок, датированных  между 1593 и 1613 годами и подписанных Робертом Миндумом (Robert Mindum).

https://mykrossovki.blogspot.com/2017/03/blog-post.html

3. Начало своей истории **рожок для обуви** черпает в эпохе Ренессанса. Время пышных балов, маскарадов и невероятно роскошных нарядов сильных мира сего. Именно в то время, король Генрих VIII, издает интересный указ. Широкую обувь носить запрещается! Только узенькие атласные туфельки, которые очень сложно и снимать, и обувать. Вот тогда и появилась первая **ложка для обуви**. И конечно же, она должна была быть под стать хозяину — инкрустированная драгоценными камнями, с богатой отделкой.https://krizis-kopilka.ru/archives/36978
4. Хотите купить старинную ложку-рожок для обуви? Недорого! [https://meshok.net/?related=Ложка+%28рожок%29+обувная.+Дореволюционная](https://meshok.net/?related=%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0+%28%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA%29+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.+%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F)

Не хотите? Ну тогда хотя бы картинки посмотрите.

Comment: Интересное оливье :)))

Comment: Артем, я говорю "рожок", про совок, ложку и лопатку ничего вроде бы не слышала. Но вообще-то надо опросить гостей и соседей.

Comment: А я с детства слышал и говорил только "ложка" :) Только потом узнал и о "рожке".

Comment: *Интересно!)))*

Comment: Страна наша большая! Вы знаете что такое мультифора?

Comment: Понятия не имею! Пишут, что файл) да?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Начав работать в Москве, спрашиваю у коллег, где взять мультифоры. И никто не понял, что мне надо. А я, в свою очередь, удивился, что эту штуку все называют файлом. :)

Comment: Ха-ха) А зачем вы обособили *в свою очередь?*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  У меня это [вводное сочетание](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_112) (грамота.ру). Мне кажется, что так оно и есть. Добавка: еще раз осмыслил и да – больше подходит на роль члена предложения, т. е. без запятых.

Comment: Но тут же значения "в свою очередь", "в ответ", разве нет?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Одновременно писали. Я изменил комментарий. Вы правы.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: а вы знаете, откуда это слово?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой От лат. "имеющий много отверстий". Региональное, сибирское   (я из Кемерова).

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: вы, как стали употреблять, сразу знали, что из латыни? Из Кемерова? Интересно) Спасибо, что сказали!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Нет, конечно, не знал. Как слова начинают употреблять? Все говорят (тем более в серьезной обстановке) – и ты, как ребенок, подхватываешь.Конечно, понятно было, что "мульти" - много. Пишут, что если к английскому применить, то будет "много для чего" - multi for.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: ну, английское 'for' к этому не имеет отношения.))

Answer (score 1):

Для меня неформальный вариант "рожка" — "**совок**". Этот предмет по форме похож на совок для детской песочницы, и его "всовывают" между пяткой и задней частью обуви. Про "*ложку*" я не слышал, видимо, это *региональное* ([здесь](https://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4497787.html) удивляются, что "ложку" можно иначе называть). Могло распространиться с расширением свободы перемещения; при описании комбинированных приспособлений для надевания обуви инвалидами это слово встречается.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Про расширение свободы перемещения не очень понял. А "совок" это питерское, шире или ваше личное?

Comment: Действительно, совок — вариант неплохой. Но «заигран» и затёрт донельзя отечественными хунвейбинами. Есть версия рожка-ложки: Ложок. Думаю, архитекторы не будут против: к двум значениям добавится третье.

Comment: Смешно!) Но только чтобы один раз пошутить) Что-то Вы придираетесь к чужим большим буквам не в начале предложения, а сами так же написали.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Не анекдот же, а шутка. Если без шуток: многие этот предмет зовут язычком.